# displaying list <vector<int> > elements

Tags: c++

I use a `vector< int >` and I want to store all the `vector`s into another. So I have chosen `list<vector<int> >`

Later I want to display all the elements hold in each `vector` in the `list`. But I'm wondering how to display them now.

If I'm using only `vector` or `list` means I can use iterator and display my `int`s. But I don't know how to do this. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested iterations, This will print each vector's data in a line:

```
list<vector<int>>  data;

// ...

for (auto &v : data)
{
    for (auto &i : v)
    {
      cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

A bit older:

```
for (list<vector<int> >::const_iterator v = data.begin(); v != data.end(); v++)
{
    for (vector<int>::const_iterator i = v->begin(); i != v->end(); i++)
    {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for your suggestion. it might be helpful . i'm just tryiin now to know how both methods work.
But i'm wondering how the auto in 1st method is working.

Comment: [`auto`](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-auto-decltype-return-value-after-function.html)  and [`ranged-based loop`](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html) are C++11 features. Read about them and enjoy using them.

Comment: cool thank u very much. Now i tried to display with 2nd method and its able to display only one vector.. might be there's no data or what i have to see.. 
anyways thanks a lot.

Comment: looks like i have to add some plug-ins if want to use c++11 features i think. any suggestions on that...

Comment: No, you need just enable it in your compiler, which compiler do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers). It contains a generic pretty-printer for C++ with support for STL containers.

So you'll just `#include` it and your

```
    list<vector<int>> data;
    cout << data;
```

will work like a bliss.